# Is there a way to provide SAML sp implementation using an Apache filter?

Tags: apache2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, service-provider

I'm really new with SAML SSO. I'm woking with an idp webapp that will support SAML authentication.

The problem is that I will need that other sp authenticate with my idp and I don't want to implement all the protocol in every platform (Python, PHP, Java, etc).

I was thinking if there's a way to implement the sp authentication flow using an apache filter.

Has someone thought about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_mellon is what you're looking for: https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon

Comment: No, I didn't. This module is written by the same team than SimpleSAMLphp. Alternatively, you can try the module from ZXID: http://www.zxid.org/html/mod_auth_saml.html. Those are AFAIK the only opensource modules for Apache. I would be interested in your feedback.

Comment: I'm going to test them by monday. By now, I'll set this as an answer ;). Thanks!

Comment: I have another question. Do you know if this apache modules work with every SAML implementation? It looks like OpenID is more standard....

Comment: It should. SAML is normalized by OASIS. OpenID is an industrial standard. Both are meant to be interoperable.

Comment: One more thing: OpenID AFAIK addresses only the Browser Web SSO use case. SAML is far more versatile. For example, it is possible to build a Web SSO with no direct communications between the SP and the IDP. This is not possible with OpenID. Aside from Web SSO, SAML can be used for many use case: Web Services security, identity propagation, etc. See http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Using Shibboleth as a SAML client in conjunction with Apache web server may be an alternative.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer.